# How to start an android app with valgrind?

Tags: android, valgrind

I've been searching for trying to find an answer to this question.
I have already installed valgrind on android phone as below step.

==================================================================

The valgrind is already in the ICS 4.0.3

The steps to enable the valgrind when building the ICS.

Step 1:
Modify the file ./build/target/product/core.mk as following.

sensorservice
+ valgrind

wpa_supplicant.conf

Step 2:

build the ICS.

from [https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/Android/UseValgrindOnAndroid]

==================================================================

Is this right one??

Anyway.. I'm also searching my question in here & find this answer.

==================================================================

You can try to clear the logcat first

prompt# adb logcat -c
prompt# adb logcat
You should be able to see the logs coming in once you triggered your application.

am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.hellojni/.HelloJni
I had problems with my shell script and i used this instead.

adb shell setprop wrap.com.example.hellojni "logwrapper /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind"

==================================================================

But, my android phone does not work.. at first step.
'prompt# adb logcat -c' make a 'waiting a target..' very very long long time...

How do I start an Android app with valgrind?

Comment: For **how to run your app through Valgrind on Android (ARM)** see my script from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235439/313113