# How to use Valgrind with android app in Eclipse on Ubuntu to find android native code memory leaks on runtime?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, native-code

How to use Valgrind with android app in Eclipse on Ubuntu to find android native code memory leaks on runtime .

Comment: For **how to build Valgrind for Android (ARM)** see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19255251/313113

For **how to run your app through Valgrind** see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235439/313113