# Can not build Android Valgrind

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

I want to check memory leak. It's the first time I use Valgrind.
I have an error that I can not find 
{VALGRIND_DIRECTORY}/Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/Valgrind.

Android ndkr10e
Ubuntu 16.04 x64
Device Lenovo A706

I followed : [Android valgrind build fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450650/android-valgrind-build-fails/19255251#19255251)

Log

```
HOME: /home/trungle
NDK: /home/trungle/Documents/Application/android-ndk-r10e
SDK: /home/trungle/Android/Sdk/
VALGRIND: valgrind-3.13.0
VALGRIND_DIRECTORY: valgrind-3.13.0
BUILD: false
adbd is already running as root
remount succeeded
cannot stat 'Inst': No such file or directory
adb root
/system/bin/sh: /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind: not found
~/Documents/Application/android-ndk-r10e/samples/hello-jni ~/Documents/Application/valgrindTool/valgrind-3.13.0
./build_valgrind.sh: line 148: android: command not found
Failure
./build_valgrind.sh: line 180: ant: command not found
~/Documents/Application/valgrindTool/valgrind-3.13.0
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.example.hellojni/.HelloJni }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.hellojni/com.example.hellojni.HelloJni} does not exist.
chmod: cannot access 'bootstrap_valgrind.sh': No such file or directory
bash: bootstrap_valgrind.sh: No such file or directory
/sdcard/*grind*: No such file or directory
/storage/sdcard0/*grind*: No such file or directory
/storage/sdcard1/*grind*: No such file or directory
```

Myscript

```
function extract()
{
     if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
         case "$1" in
             *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf "$1"     ;;
             *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf "$1"     ;;
             *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$1"      ;;
             *.rar)       unrar x "$1"      ;;
             *.gz)        gunzip "$1"       ;;
             *.tar)       tar xvf "$1"      ;;
             *.tbz2)      tar xvjf "$1"     ;;
             *.tgz)       tar xvzf "$1"     ;;
             *.zip)       unzip "$1"        ;;
             *.Z)         uncompress "$1"   ;;
             *.7z)        7z x "$1"         ;;
             *)           echo "$1 cannot be extracted via >extract<" ;;
         esac
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
     fi
}

RUN_HELLO_JNI_THROUGH_VALGRIND=true
VALGRIND_VERSION="3.13.0"
VALGRIND_EXTENSION=".tar.bz2"
VALGRIND_DIRECTORY="valgrind-${VALGRIND_VERSION}"
VALGRIND_TARBALL="valgrind-${VALGRIND_VERSION}${VALGRIND_EXTENSION}"

# Only download Valgrind tarball again if not already downloaded
if [[ ! -f "${VALGRIND_TARBALL}" ]]; then
  wget -v -nc "ftp://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/${VALGRIND_TARBALL}"
fi

# Only extract Valgrind tarball again if not already extracted
if [[ ! -d "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY" ]]; then
  extract "$VALGRIND_TARBALL"
fi
echo "HOME: $HOME"
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$HOME/Documents/Application/android-ndk-r10e"
# Ensure ANDROID_NDK_HOME is set
if [[ ! -z "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" ]]; then
  export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$HOME/Documents/Application/android-ndk-r10e"
fi
echo "NDK: $ANDROID_NDK_HOME"
# Ensure ANDOID_SDK_HOME is set
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/"
if [[ ! -z "$ANDROID_SDK_HOME" ]]; then
  export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/"
fi
echo "SDK: $ANDROID_SDK_HOME"

if [[ ! -d "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY" ]];
then
  echo "Problem with extracting Valgrind from $VALGRIND_TARBALL into $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY!!!"
  exit -1
fi

echo "VALGRIND: $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

# Move to extracted directory
cd "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

# ARM Toolchain
ARCH_ABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
export AR="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export LD="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export CC="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
export CXX="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"

[[ ! -d "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" || ! -f "$AR" || ! -f "$LD" || ! -f "$CC" || ! -f "$CXX" ]] && echo "Make sure AR, LD, CC, CXX variables are defined correctly. Ensure ANDROID_NDK_HOME is defined also" && exit -1

# Configure build
export HWKIND="zenphone5"
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-18
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_$HWKIND"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/arch-arm"

# BUG: For some reason file command is unable to detect if the file does not exist with ! -f , it says it doesn't exist even when it does!!!
echo "VALGRIND_DIRECTORY: $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

BUILD=false

if [[ "${VALGRIND_DIRECTORY}/Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/Valgrind" = *"No such file or directoryy"* ]]; then
  BUILD=true
fi

echo "BUILD: $BUILD" 

if [[ "$BUILD" = true ]];
then
  ./configure --prefix="/data/local/Inst" \
  --host="armv7-unknown-linux" \
  --target="armv7-unknown-linux" \
  --with-tmpdir="/sdcard"

  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't configure!" && exit -1

  # Determine the number of jobs (commands) to be run simultaneously by GNU Make
  NO_CPU_CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)

  if [ $NO_CPU_CORES -le 8 ]; then
    JOBS=$(($NO_CPU_CORES+1))
  else
    JOBS=${NO_CPU_CORES}
  fi

  # Compile Valgrind 
  make -j "${JOBS}"

  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't compile!" && exit -1

  # Install Valgrind locally
  make -j "${JOBS}" install DESTDIR="$(pwd)/Inst"
  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't install!" && exit -1
fi

# Push local Valgrind installtion to the phone
if [[ $(adb shell ls -ld /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind) = *"No such file or directory"* ]];
then
  adb root
  adb remount
  adb shell "[ ! -d /data/local/Inst ] && mkdir /data/local/Inst"
  adb push Inst /sdcard/
  echo "adb root"
  adb shell "ls -l /data/local/Inst"

  # Ensure Valgrind on the phone is running
  adb shell "/data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind --version"

  # Add Valgrind executable to PATH (this might fail)
  adb shell "export PATH=$PATH:/data/local/Inst/bin/"
fi

if [ $RUN_HELLO_JNI_THROUGH_VALGRIND = true ]; then
  PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

  # The location of the Hello JNI sample application
  HELLO_JNI_PATH="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/samples/hello-jni"

  pushd "$HELLO_JNI_PATH" 

  # Update build target to the desired Android SDK version
  ANDROID_PROJECT_TARGET="android-18"
  android update project --target "$ANDROID_PROJECT_TARGET" --path . --name hello-jni --subprojects

  # Enable Android NDK build with Ant
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <project name="HelloJni" basedir="." default="debug">

    <target name="-pre-build">
      <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" depends="android_rules.clean">
      <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="clean"/>
      </exec>
    </target> 

    </project>
  ' > "custom_rules.xml"

  # Set NDK HOME for Ant (only if not already set)
  if ! grep -P -q "ndk.dir=.+" "local.properties" ; then
    echo -e "\nndk.dir=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" >> "local.properties"
  fi

  # Fix for Java 8 warning (warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release)
  echo "java.compilerargs=-Xlint:-options" >> "ant.properties"

  # Workaround INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES error
  adb uninstall "$PACKAGE"

  # Build Hello JNI project in debug mode and install it on the device
  ant clean && ant debug && ant installd

  popd

  cd ..  

  # Start HelloJNI app 
  adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n $PACKAGE/.HelloJni

  # Make the script executable
  chmod a+x bootstrap_valgrind.sh

  # Run application through Valgrind on the phone
  /usr/bin/env bash bootstrap_valgrind.sh

  adb shell ls -lR "/sdcard/*grind*"
  adb shell ls -lR "/storage/sdcard0/*grind*"
  adb shell ls -lR "/storage/sdcard1/*grind*"
fi

exit 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android valgrind build fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450650/android-valgrind-build-fails)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how your test

```
if [[ "${VALGRIND_DIRECTORY}/Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/Valgrind" = *"No such file or directoryy"* ]]; then
    BUILD=true
fi
```

is supposed to work. For a start there is a spelling mistake (double y in directory). Also if your filesystem is case sensitive there should be no capital V in valgrind.

Secondly, your path looks wrong. Your `configure` command is using "/data/local/Inst" as the prefix, but the above test expands to

> valgrind-3.13.0/Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/Valgrind

I think that the test should be something like

```
if [[ ! -e /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind ]] ; then
    BUILD = true
fi
```

Alternatively, if your script is supposed to be checking for the in-place Valgrind (the one that gets build in the source directory), that whould be something like

```
if [[ ! -e coregrind/valgrind ]]; then
    BUILD=true
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. But spelling mistake is not problem and I want to that to check some another problem.
I have some problem where is "Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/Valgrind" in directory and how I can create that.

Comment: I suggest that you simplify the script and ensure that `configure` and `make` execute.

Comment: I can not find Inst. Im sure ./configure and make execute done. Where  I can find that