# Valgrind can't create temp files

Tags: android, valgrind

i'm trying to run app with valgrind on android, but i get error VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file. I read that problem often happens on android but i didn't found any solution. I'm doing everything like on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531496/cant-run-a-java-android-program-with-valgrind/19235439#19235439), with one difference in second script i use batch not bash.

`08-28 12:13:53.820: I/dalvikvm(19303): Exec: /system/bin/sh -c logwrapper sh /data/local/hellojni_valgrind.sh /system/bin/app_process /system/bin --application '--nice-name=com.example.hellojni' com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 28 3 'android.app.ActivityThread' 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): ==19315== VG_(mkstemp): failed to create temp file: /data/data/com.example.hellojni 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): valgrind: Startup or configuration error: 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): valgrind: Can't create client cmdline file in ??8L?8 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/sh(19312): valgrind: Unable to start up properly. Giving up. 08-28 12:13:53.850: I/logwrapper(19312): sh terminated by exit(1)`

Comment: Got same problem, still using bash for second script.

Comment: Make sure that given directory exists prior runnign valgrind and that it is writeable to valgrind process: /data/data/com.example.hellojni

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember, it was over 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try let valgrind to use default directory '/data/local/tmp' and **chmod 777** permission to '/data/local/tmp'