# Screen freezes when I run Android program with Valgrind

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

I am new to Valgrind. I learnt how to use Valgrind on Android from this thread:
[Can't run a Java Android program with Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531496/cant-run-a-java-android-program-with-valgrind)

The scripts on my Desktop are almost the same as the original ones, except that I built the Valgrind using aarch-64 toolchains manually and ran Valgrind on Samsung S6. I have tested the Valgrind on Android using compiled c binary, and it worked. When I tested the HelloJni application, the screen froze and I cannot see the output of the application. I used "adb shell top" to see the running process, and there was a process called:

```
{main} valgrind --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --compress-strings=no --compress-pos=no --log-file=/sdcard/valgrind.log.%p --tool=callgrind
```

When I kill this process, there were some log files on /sdcard/. And the logcat worked OK. So, Valgrind did work on the background, but I could not see the application run on the foreground.

I am really stuck here. Anyone has any ideas?

Also, does anyone know how to run Valgrind on an apk file?

Thanks a lot.

My code:

build_valgrind.sh: (I built my Valgrind somewhere else and pushed it to /data/local/Inst already)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set -x 

adb root
adb remount

# Ensure Valgrind on the phone is running
adb shell "/data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind --version"

# Add Valgrind executable to PATH (this might fail)
adb shell "export PATH=$PATH:/data/local/Inst/bin/"

export NDK_HOME=$HOME/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e
export SDK_HOME=$HOME/Downloads/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$SDK_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$SDK_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
RUN_HELLO_JNI_THROUGH_VALGRIND=true

cd valgrind-3.11.0

if [ $RUN_HELLO_JNI_THROUGH_VALGRIND = true ]; then
  PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

  # The location of the Hello JNI sample application
  HELLO_JNI_PATH="$NDK_HOME/samples/hello-jni"

  pushd "$HELLO_JNI_PATH" 

  # Update build target to the desired Android SDK version
  ANDROID_PROJECT_TARGET="android-18"
  android update project --target "$ANDROID_PROJECT_TARGET" --path . --name hello-jni --subprojects

  # Enable Android NDK build with Ant
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <project name="HelloJni" basedir="." default="debug">

    <target name="-pre-build">
      <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" depends="android_rules.clean">
      <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="clean"/>
      </exec>
    </target> 

    </project>
  ' > "custom_rules.xml"

  # Set NDK HOME for Ant (only if not already set)
  if ! grep -P -q "ndk.dir=.+" "local.properties" ; then
    echo -e "\nndk.dir=$NDK_HOME" >> "local.properties"
  fi

  # Fix for Java 8 warning (warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release)
  echo "java.compilerargs=-Xlint:-options" >> "ant.properties"

  # Workaround INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES error
  adb uninstall "$PACKAGE"

  # Build Hello JNI project in debug mode and install it on the device
  ant clean && ant debug && ant installd

  popd

  cd ..  

  # Start HelloJNI app 
  adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n $PACKAGE/.HelloJni

  # Make the script executable
  chmod a+x bootstrap_valgrind.sh

  # Run application through Valgrind on the phone
  /usr/bin/env bash bootstrap_valgrind.sh

  adb shell ls -lR "/sdcard/*grind*"
  adb shell ls -lR "/storage/sdcard0/*grind*"
  adb shell ls -lR "/storage/sdcard1/*grind*"
fi
```

bootstrap_valgrind.sh:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

adb push start_valgrind.sh /data/local/
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/local/start_valgrind.sh" 

adb root
adb shell setprop wrap.$PACKAGE "logwrapper /data/local/start_valgrind.sh"

echo "wrap.$PACKAGE: $(adb shell getprop wrap.$PACKAGE)"



adb shell am force-stop $PACKAGE
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n $PACKAGE/.HelloJni

adb logcat -c
adb logcat


exit 0
```

start_valgrind.sh:

```bash
#!/system/bin/sh

PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

# Callgrind tool
VGPARAMS='--error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --compress-strings=no --compress-pos=no --log-file=/sdcard/valgrind.log.%p --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/sdcard/callgrind.out.%p'

# Memcheck tool
#VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file=/sdcard/valgrind.log.%p --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes'

export TMPDIR=/data/data/$PACKAGE

exec /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind $VGPARAMS $*
```

Comment: Sometimes it even causes the reboot of Android system. I found the problem was caused by --trace-children=yes. If I remove it, it ran well. My guess is tracing all the children will comsume a lot of memory.