# Can not run android app with valgrind

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

I create project Hello JNI and write state to test leak such as:

```
int* requieData = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

This is my script build_valgrind.sh
I can run ./configure but does not any valgrind log can show.

My build_valgrind.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set -x 

function extract()
{
     if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
         case "$1" in
             *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf "$1"     ;;
             *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf "$1"     ;;
             *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$1"      ;;
             *.rar)       unrar x "$1"      ;;
             *.gz)        gunzip "$1"       ;;
             *.tar)       tar xvf "$1"      ;;
             *.tbz2)      tar xvjf "$1"     ;;
             *.tgz)       tar xvzf "$1"     ;;
             *.zip)       unzip "$1"        ;;
             *.Z)         uncompress "$1"   ;;
             *.7z)        7z x "$1"         ;;
             *)           echo "$1 cannot be extracted via >extract<" ;;
         esac
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
     fi
}

RUN_HELLO_JNI_THROUGH_VALGRIND=true
VALGRIND_VERSION="3.13.0"
VALGRIND_EXTENSION=".tar.bz2"
VALGRIND_DIRECTORY="valgrind-${VALGRIND_VERSION}"
VALGRIND_TARBALL="valgrind-${VALGRIND_VERSION}${VALGRIND_EXTENSION}"

# Only download Valgrind tarball again if not already downloaded
if [[ ! -f "${VALGRIND_TARBALL}" ]]; then
  wget -v -nc "ftp://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/${VALGRIND_TARBALL}"
fi

# Only extract Valgrind tarball again if not already extracted
if [[ ! -d "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY" ]]; then
  extract "$VALGRIND_TARBALL"
fi
echo "HOME: $HOME"
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle"
# Ensure ANDROID_NDK_HOME is set
if [[ ! -z "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" ]]; then
  export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle"
fi
echo "NDK: $ANDROID_NDK_HOME"
# Ensure ANDOID_SDK_HOME is set
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/"
if [[ ! -z "$ANDROID_SDK_HOME" ]]; then
  export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/"
fi
echo "SDK: $ANDROID_SDK_HOME"

if [[ ! -d "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY" ]];
then
  echo "Problem with extracting Valgrind from $VALGRIND_TARBALL into $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY!!!"
  exit -1
fi

echo "VALGRIND: $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

# Move to extracted directory
cd "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

# ARM Toolchain
ARCH_ABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
export AR="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export LD="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export CC="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
export CXX="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"

[[ ! -d "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" || ! -f "$AR" || ! -f "$LD" || ! -f "$CC" || ! -f "$CXX" ]] && echo "Make sure AR, LD, CC, CXX variables are defined correctly. Ensure ANDROID_NDK_HOME is defined also" && exit -1

# Configure build
export HWKIND="lenovo"
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-18
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_$HWKIND"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/arch-arm"

# BUG: For some reason file command is unable to detect if the file does not exist with ! -f , it says it doesn't exist even when it does!!!
echo "VALGRIND_DIRECTORY: $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

# ModeBuildTest
BUILD=true

if [[ "$BUILD" = true ]];
then
  ./configure --prefix="/data/local/Inst" \
  --host="armv7-unknown-linux" \
  --target="armv7-unknown-linux" \
  --with-tmpdir="/sdcard"

  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't configure!" && exit -1

  # Determine the number of jobs (commands) to be run simultaneously by GNU Make
  NO_CPU_CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)

  if [ $NO_CPU_CORES -le 8 ]; then
    JOBS=$(($NO_CPU_CORES+1))
  else
    JOBS=${NO_CPU_CORES}
  fi

  # Compile Valgrind 
  make -j "${JOBS}"

  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't compile!" && exit -1

  # Install Valgrind locally
  make -j "${JOBS}" install DESTDIR="$(pwd)/Inst"
  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't install!" && exit -1
fi

# Push local Valgrind installtion to the phone
if [[ $(adb shell ls -ld /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind) = *"No such file or directory"* ]];
then
  adb root
  adb remount
  adb shell "[ ! -d /data/local/Inst ] && mkdir /data/local/Inst"
  adb push Inst /
  adb shell "ls -l /data/local/Inst"

  # Ensure Valgrind on the phone is running
  adb shell "/data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind --version"

  # Add Valgrind executable to PATH (this might fail)
  adb shell "export PATH=$PATH:/data/local/Inst/bin/"
  echo "Push local Valgrind installtion"
fi

echo "Buil Valgrind end"

if [ $RUN_HELLO_JNI_THROUGH_VALGRIND = true ]; 
then
  PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

  # The location of the Hello JNI sample application
  HELLO_JNI_PATH="$HOME/Documents/Project/HelloJNI"

    # Workaround INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES error
  adb uninstall "$PACKAGE"

  cd $HELLO_JNI_PATH

  ./gradlew assembleArmDebug

  ./gradlew installArmDebug

  # Build Hello JNI project in debug mode and install it on the device

  echo "Finish Installation"

  # Start HelloJNI app 
  #adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n $PACKAGE/.HelloJni

  cd $HOME/Documents/Application/valgrindTool

  # Make the script executable
  chmod a+x bootstrap_valgrind.sh

  # Run application through Valgrind on the phone
  /usr/bin/env bash bootstrap_valgrind.sh

  adb shell ls -lR "/sdcard/*grind*"
  adb shell ls -lR "/storage/sdcard0/*grind*"
  adb shell ls -lR "/storage/sdcard1/*grind*"
fi

echo "Call helloWord"

exit 0
```

And this is bootstrap_valgrind.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

adb push start_valgrind.sh /data/local/
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/start_valgrind.sh 

adb root
adb shell setprop wrap.$PACKAGE "logwrapper /data/local/start_valgrind.sh"

echo "wrap.$PACKAGE: $(adb shell getprop wrap.$PACKAGE)"

adb shell am force-stop $PACKAGE
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n $PACKAGE/.HelloJni

adb logcat -c
adb logcat

exit 0
```

This is start_valgrind.sh

```
# Define the package name
PACKAGE="com.example.hellojni"

# Memcheck tool: a memory error detector
VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --log-file=/sdcard/hellojni.log.%p --leak-check=yes --leak-resolution=high --show-reachable=yes --undef-value-errors --read-var-info=yes'

# Massif tool: a heap profiler
# VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.log.%p --tool=massif --massif-out-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.massif.out.%p'

# Callgrind tool: a cache and branch-prediction profiler
# VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.log.%p --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.callgrind.out.%p'

# Helgrind tool: a thread error detector
# VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.log.%p --tool=helgrind --helgrind-out-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.helgrind.out.%p'

# DHAT: a dynamic heap analysis tool
# VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.log.%p --tool=exp-dhat --exp-dhat-out-file=/sdcard/enzo_lync_profiles/enzo_lync_profile.dhat.out.%p'

export TMPDIR=/data/local/Ints/
exec /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind $VGPARAMS $*
```

My device armeabi-v7(show by android studio) but when I use this cript, device show:

```
Hello from JNI leak valgrind !  Compiled with ABI armeabi.
```

My question: Why output show armeabi? I think it is armeabi-v7.
And I can not see anylog about memory leak. What is wrong in the script?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Anybody help me...

Comment: up.................

Comment: up..............

Comment: up...................

Comment: hi did you find anything?