# Android, start valgrind permission denied when launched under logwrapper

Tags: android, shell, adb, native, valgrind

I'm trying to use `valgrind` on android, and have some problems. When I launch app under `valgrind` I got following errors(in logcat):

```
         logwrapper  W  type=1400 audit(0.0:73): avc: denied { execute } for name="start_valgrind.sh" dev="dm-1" ino=654102 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tcla ss=file permissive=0

                     E  executing /data/local/start_valgrind.sh failed: Permission denied
  start_valgrind.sh  I  executing /data/local/start_valgrind.sh failed: Permission denied
                     I  start_valgrind.sh terminated by exit(255)
```

Preconditions:

1. I builded valgring valgrind-3.13.0 on my machine and push it on
   rooted nexus 6P, 8.1.0 OS. (I also used emulator 8.0 +
   valgrind-3.11.0 - same effect)
2. I set prop `adb shell setprop wrap.$PACKAGE \"logwrapper /data/local/start_valgrind.sh\"` (start_valgrinds.sh script
   from below link)
3. I used instructions from here
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235439/313113 .
4. I did `chmod -R 777 /data/local/Inst/` (location for valgrind bin).
5. I did `chmod 777 /data/local/start_valgrind.sh` (start script, see 2 item)
6. I launched app like that: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n $PACKAGE/.MainActivity`
7. I use Hello world native JNI app.

Maybe problem that `logwrapper` can not start script `/data/local/start_valgrind.sh` due to that fact that it does not have enouph permissions, but how to add those permissions.?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @ArturLatoszewski not yet, put it off until better times.

Comment: have you been building valgrind on OSX? Which version of NDK have you used?

Comment: OSX, ndk version most probably was r12b, not sure it mattered though.

Answer (score 3):

The logwrapper can't execute the shell script as it has SELinux permission issue. Try to disable teh SELinux enforcement with below command
`setenforce 0`

Answer (score -1):

Try to move start_valgrind.sh to /system/bin and set mode 755